# Pre-loaded iFrame Content

Tags: html, iframe

I'm using an iframe in my page to display an embedded video.

The issue I have is that I already have the embed code I need, and can I render it directly into the iframe when I load the full page.

However, the iframe always seems to attempt to load a src attribute.

I'd like the iframe to keep the content I provide in it on render:

```
...
<div class="iframeWrapper">
 <iframe>
  <html>
   <body>
    <div>I already know this is the iframe content I want.</div>
   </body>
  </html>
 </iframe>
</div>
...
```

The basic premise is that I'd prefer not to have to make a second request for the contents of the iframe, when I already know what the contents are supposed to be the first time through.

Is this even possible?

Thanks.

Edit: The iframe is purely for sandboxing.  And not currently negotiable.

Comment: If you know the code already, why are you loading it in an iframe? What are you attempting to gain?

Comment: If you already have the content, why do you need the iframe at all?  Just remove the iframe tags from the code in your example, and you have exactly what you need.  What functionality is the iframe providing you with that you can't just put the HTML into the page to begin with?

Comment: Maybe he's trying to sandbox CSS or JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var stuff = "<div>I already know this is the iframe content I want.</div>";
document.getElementById('iframe').contentDocument.body.innerHTML = stuff;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EcusH/

Comment: I tried that before, but no luck.  I guess I'll give it another go.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is old, but for future reference there is an attribute called `srcdoc` for `iframe`s that allow you to provide the content directly.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_srcdoc.asp

Comment: Simple and effective. For me the best answer. Thx.